# NFS read timeout using c poll()

Tags: c, linux, nfs

We have a NFS server which may sometimes have latency issues which then causes problem in my client, so Im trying to find a way to timeout, when it takes more time ( eg. > 200 ms) to read from NFS. Here is a minimal example which uses `poll` function to try to handle this issue:

```
struct pollfd pfd[1];
pfd[0].fd = fileno(file); //file opened previously using fopen 
pfd[0].events = POLLIN;
ret = poll(pfd, 1, 200); //wait for 200 milliseconds
if(ret == 0)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "poll timed out\n");
}
```

To test this I introduced latency of `400 ms` using linux `tc` command.
My understanding with `poll` is that, with `POLLIN` event, and with the added `400 ms` latency, there should be a timeout. But somehow it doesnot happen and `ret` is always `> 0`

Is using `poll` the correct way to handle NFS latency issues?

Comment: After considering janneb's answer, note that NFS can be slow (especially compared to a fast NIC card). So, using shared memory buffers, in conjunction with threads and/or io_uring could help. Also, io_uring and/or `PACKET_MMAP` could reduce unnecessary data copying on the socket to the client.

Comment: Unfortunately I think Linux `poll` doesn't work for files, only sockets. Linux generally isn't designed for asynchronous file IO. You could try using the relatively new `io_uring` API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, poll() is not the correct choice. In POSIX a regular file is always considered ready, so poll() will return immediately but the actual I/O will still block.

You might do the I/O in a separate thread, or on Linux you could look into using io_uring.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Unfortunately Im bound to use only a single thread. The code is actually used in a apache module which uses prefork model with some non thread safe libs. I will read through io_uring in detail and get back.

Comment: Just for information, if we go for a separate thread then still how to check the timeouts. I mean in separate thread, we can use for eg. fread to read the file in parts but it doesnt seem to have such timeouts. Any suggestions here ?

Comment: @astre The I/O thread will block, yes, so you need to keep track of the timeout in the parent thread, and if a timeout occurs you can kill the I/O thread with pthread_cancel().

Comment: @janneb sometimes you can't even kill threads that are stuck in IO on Linux!